# Identify feature names from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have a piece of code as follow:

```
# transforming data to best 20 features
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=20)
fs.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train = fs.transform(X_train)
X_test = fs.transform(X_test)



# what are scores for the features
for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
print('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))
# plot the scores
plt.bar([i for i in range(len(fs.scores_))], fs.scores_)
plt.show()
```

The plot gives me the output as indicated in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o55UL.png), I'm wondering how can I identify the actual feature names of these features instead of "1-20" ? I tried get_support() but it gives an error since my data is in array format as I used train_test_split.

Answer (score 0):

The features are in the same order as the data inside the X_train array. So in order to get your feature names you should extract them before making the X_train to a numpy array. If you are using a pandas dataframe named `df` what you can do is:

```
for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
    print(f'Feature {df.columns[i]}: {fs.scores_[i]}')
```

Comment: @Brian Wu Did the solution help?